# org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Monitor does not retun correct values for the 2-nd monitor

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I want to get dimensions and zoom of all monitors.
Code:

```
package root.viewer.rcp.util;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Monitor;
import org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI;

public class ApplicationMonitorsManager
{
  public Monitor[] monitors;
  //public Display display = new Display();
  
  public ApplicationMonitorsManager()
  {
    
  }
  
  public Monitor[] getMonitors()
  {
    //Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay();
    monitors = display.getMonitors();
    return monitors;
  }
}
```

Values for primary monitor are correct:

```
clientHeight    2070    
clientWidth 3840    
clientX 0   
clientY 0   
handle  200823  
height  2160    
width   3840    
x   0   
y   0   
zoom    225
```

The second monitor has the same resolution, but zoom is 125%. Values I get:

```
clientHeight    3798    
clientWidth 6912    
clientX 6912    
clientY 0   
handle  200517  
height  3888    
width   6912    
x   6912    
y   0   
zoom    225
```

Any idea what is wrong, please?

Does not matter if I try `Display display = Display.getCurrent()` or `Display display = PlatformUI.createDisplay()`. For `Display display = new Display()` application crashes with `SWTException: Invalid thread access`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SWT does not yet support different zoom values:

[**Eclipse SWT issue #131** - *[Multi-Monitor] SWT applications to support and work with different zoom values per Shell.*](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/issues/131)